# Error Occurred During Flow "My_FLow_name": The flow tried to update these records: a0m

Tags: process-builder, salesforce-id

I am getting an error Email, but i am not able to locate the issue. As per the email the record (a0m15000007MtkEAAS) is causing the error but I think there is something else and not this record causing error.

> [breadwinner_qbo__Opportunity__c  is lookup to opportunity]

Error mail screenshot : https://unsee.cc/dabezotu/

My best guess is for record `a0m15000007MthRAAS` is the wrong object Id and is getting assigned instead of something like `006...`. The record being assigned is `00k1500000NFqSv`.

I am I correct? Is there anything else wrong? Also if i am correct then why does the  email says record `a0m15000007MtkEAAS` is causing this failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. The error...

> breadwinner_qbo__Opportunity__c is Lookup to Opportunity

... means that you have a field, `breadwinner_qbo__Opportunity__c` that has a Lookup relationship to the standard Opportunity object. However, in your Flow you're setting the value of that to a different object so it's throwing an exception.

This is easy to fix, just set the value of `breadwinner_qbo__Opportunity__c` to that of an Opportunity it should reference.

> also if i am correct then why mail says record (a0m15000007MtkEAAS) is causing this failure?

We'd really need the full error and maybe have a more detailed view of your flow. If I had a guess I would say that your record `a0m` is executing the flow and trying to assign `00k` to a Lookup that expects `006` (Opportunity).